# Perl Regex Replace and save to variable

Tags: regex, perl, variables, extract

```
$LDAP = ldap://sspdir.managed.entrust.com/ou=Entrust Managed Services SSP CA,ou=Certification Authorities,o=Entrust,c=US?cACertificate;binary,crossCertificatePair;binary
```

I am trying to extract 2 strings from this code ldap directory. The first i want:

```
$LDAP_host = sspdir.managed.entrust.com
```

and second...

```
$LDAP_base = ou=Entrust Managed Services SSP CA,ou=Certification Authorities,o=Entrust,c=US
```

My code is below, it produces constant mismatches in my output and I cannot figure out why:

```
my $LDAP_host = $LDAP;
my $LDAP_base = $LDAP;
$LDAP_host =~ s|^ldap:\/\/(.*)\/|$1|i;
$LDAP_base =~ s|"\/"(.*)\?|$1|i;
```

Comment: If this is an LDAP string, there should be a suitable module to parse it.

Answer (score 3):

I'd use:

```
 my ($LDAP_host, $LDAP_base) = $LDAP=~ m{ // ([^/]+) / (ou=[^?]+) }x;
```

or, if you'd like to check the start of the string too:

```
 my ($LDAP_host, $LDAP_base) = $LDAP=~ m{ ^ldap:// ([^/]+) / (ou=[^?]+) \? }x;
```

Regards

rbo

Answer (score 1):

```
my $str = "ldap://sspdir.managed.entrust.com/ou=Entrust Managed Services SSP CA,ou=Certification    Authorities,o=Entrust,c=US?cACertificate;binary,crossCertificatePair;binary";
my ($LDAP_host, $LDAP_base) = ($str =~ m!ldap://([^/]+)/([^?]+)!);
print "$LDAP_host  $LDAP_base\n";
```

Answer (score 1):

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my $LDAP='ldap://sspdir.managed.entrust.com/ou=Entrust Managed Services SSP CA,ou=Certification Authorities,o=Entrust,c=US?cACertificate;binary,crossCertificatePair;binary';

my($LDAP_host, $LDAP_base) = $LDAP =~ m{ldap://([^/]+?)/(.*?)\?.*};
print $LDAP_host, "\n";
print $LDAP_base, "\n";
```

produces

```
sspdir.managed.entrust.com
ou=Entrust Managed Services SSP CA,ou=Certification Authorities,o=Entrust,c=US
```

Answer (score 0):

This should do what you want:

```
my $LDAP_host = $LDAP;
my $LDAP_base = $LDAP;
$LDAP_host =~ s|^ldap:\/\/(.*)\/.*|$1|i;
$LDAP_base =~ s|^ldap:\/\/.*\/(.*)\?.*|$1|i;
```

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want change the original string you could try this:

```
my ($host) = $LDAP =~ /^ldap:\/\/(.*)\//i;
```

Also, if you use delimiters other than // in search and replaces,
 you don't need to escape the forward slashes.

```
$LDAP_host =~ s{^ldap://(.*)/.*}{$1}i;
```

Answer (score 0):

Please find below an amature way of implementing the same using perl.

```
my $LDAP = "ldap://sspdir.managed.entrust.com/ou=Entrust Managed Services SSP CA,ou=Certification Authorities,o=Entrust,c=US?cACertificate;binary,crossCertificatePair;binary";
$LDAP =~ '^\w+\W+(.*)/(.*)\?.*$';
$LDAP_host = $1;
$LDAP_base = $2;
print "\$LDAP_base => $LDAP_base\n\$LDAP_host => $LDAP_host\n";
```

The output would be like:

$LDAP_base => ou=Entrust Managed Services SSP CA,ou=Certification Authorities,o=Entrust,c=US
$LDAP_host => sspdir.managed.entrust.com